# Run NodeJS script 24 hours a day

Tags: node.js, deployment, cloud

I've built a script that automatically updates my specific Youtube video's title based on its viewer, something like what Tom Scott did some times ago. I got it running well and fine on my local computer, but I want to make it run 24/7 hours.

How can I do that?

I tried putting it on Heroku but it doesn't feel right since all I want to do is run a script and then let it running without any visitor. Should I get a hosting service without a domain? or what? I'm a very beginner to these cloud computing things.

Here's the link to the repository if you have any interest: https://github.com/SnekNOTSnake/youtube-updater

Comment: Either have a computer on 24/7, or rent one

Comment: Should I rent a cloud computer?

Comment: If you need to.

Comment: I'm not really sure, renting a cloud computer is like having a virtual computer on the Internet. You could do anything a computer can do including running my script 24/7. Am I wrong?

Comment: Like I said *Either have a computer on 24/7, or rent one.* Pick one. Those are your options. Both will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right IDEA. AWS, Google, Azure any of those will work. Setup your node server, don't route an elastic IP to a domain (sounds like you already know this). AWS is only a few bucks a month for a small, but capable insistence. A small AWS insistence will do far more than you need. The one thing that you need to consider is a second instance as micro-service monitor. It will monitor all services you are running, in this case one. Whenever your server drops, which inevitably every server drops for reasons I won't get into here, a micro-service monitor will restart your server, configured to your liking. At the end of each day, week or whatever you can check the micro-service monitoring platform your using to see if your server dropped at all, if its been sending request with the frequency you desire and all that. There are several options for monitor, one is you can write your own service-monitoring platform. The other are free-open source options, or you can pay a few buck (which in this case probably is not necessary) and get something premium. Here is an article that talks about Micro-services, monitoring and NodeJS.

- [Geekflare Article about Microservices, monitoring and Node.JS](https://geekflare.com/nodejs-monitoring-tools/)

Comment: I re-read your question, and my answer and I was just thinking that for your purposes, you probably, wont have to monitor anything, but you do risk your server droping due to external forces and you page not updating, though in your case, being that your program is very simple, you could probably go several months without having your server drop. For me, I have to restart my server any time aws does an upgrade, or I get an occassional (rare but has happened) unexpected error.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer sir, sorry for the late answer. I was doing another project, https://sns-blog.netlify.app. So, it's all good, right? I just need to run my script from Cloud Virtual Machine provided by the big names above. I'll try to use the monitoring system you mentioned, but if it's too much I'll just have to manually restart the script whenever it goes down (I think they have a notification for cases like this or something).

Comment: Of course its all good bud, far as I know SO is a marathon style Q&A not a sprint if ya follow. I really think, if it were me, course its not, so hypothetically speaking; if it were me, I would run your code without the monitoring system, see how long it will do its job with out dropping. The one thing I don't like about the cloud is it has to reset its servers, and all of its millions of machines, but they will let you know when that will happen. Just try it out. Later if you run other processes, or add complexity to your code, only then consider a monitor.